# Problem with wxWidgets on Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, osx-snow-leopard, wxwidgets, static-linking

I have a problem with getting compiled an wxWidget-application. I have installed the latest version of the library as follows:

```
set arch_flags="-arch x86_64 "
./configure -with-osx_cocoa --disable-shared --disable-compat24 --enable-unicode --enable-universal-binary CFLAGS="$arch_flags" CXXFLAGS="$arch_flags" CPPFLAGS="$arch_flags" LDFLAGS="$arch_flags" OBJCFLAGS="$arch_flags" OBJCXXFLAGS="$arch_flags"
sudo make install
```

I'am trying to compile a simple hello-world example with:

```
WXWIDGETS = -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.9/
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -Wall -Wextra -fmessage-length=0

CXX = $(shell wx-config --cxx)

PROGRAM = wxProjectExample

OBJECTS = $(PROGRAM).o

# implementation

.SUFFIXES:      .o .cpp

.cpp.o :
 $(CXX) -c `wx-config --static=yes --libs` `wx-config --static=yes --cxxflags` -o $@ $<

all:    $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM):     $(OBJECTS)
 $(CXX) -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJECTS) `wx-config --libs`

clean:
 rm -f *.o $(PROGRAM)
```

But the compilation fails while linking with:

```
ld: warning: in /System/Library/Frameworks//QuickTime.framework/QuickTime, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: in /usr/lib/libwx_macud-2.8.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols:
  "wxWindowBase::DoSetVirtualSize(int, int)", referenced from:
      vtable for MyFramein wxProjectExample.o
```

Where could be a problem or have somebody had similar problems with this framework?

Thx.

PS
System: SnowLeopard (64 bit) 10.6.5. with an intel proc, gcc 4.2.

Comment: The install package may have a bug. Did you try posting your question in http://wxforum.shadonet.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that you have `libwx_xxx` in `/usr/lib` when the default installation prefix is `/usr/local`. Are you sure you don't have multiple incompatible libraries versions on your system?

Also, when using static linking the libraries containing the dependencies of your code must come *after* the object file referencing them so the `wx-config --libs` part should be at the end of your rule.

Comment: How can i test, whether is it the problem? i have compiled the library several times and installed it with 'make install'. For testing i have removed the library with: rm -f  /usr/bin/wx*
rm -r  /usr/include/wx*
rm -r  /usr/lib/wx
rm -f  /usr/lib/libwx*
rm -f  /usr/local/bin/wx*
rm -r  /usr/local/include/wx*
rm -r  /usr/local/lib/wx
rm -f  /usr/local/lib/libwx* and installed one more time, but i get the same error.

Comment: not the same errors, but only one: ld: warning: in /System/Library/Frameworks//QuickTime.framework/QuickTime, missing required architecture x86_64 in file

Comment: The warning about QT might be harmless.

As for "how to test" -- this depends on how you installed it. Again, by default it wouldn't install under `/usr` at all.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed this problem by adding the path to the new wx-binaries to PATH
$ export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/2.8.11/bin:$PATH

i'm using brew to install wxmac.